# Interface naming convention in Java?

Tags: java, interface

Is there any convention on how to name your interfaces?
I do not mean the implementations, just the interface!

What about the suffix '-able'? Like `Runnable`, `Closeable`, `Serializable`? When to use this?

Comment: This question has been already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275344/java-interface-naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

A common design pattern in Java is to give your interface a very basic name, such as `Graph`, and then give the implementation the suffix `Impl`, such as `GraphImpl`.

Comment: Too generic IMHO. What if you have several implementations ?

Comment: If I want to create an interface with methods for drawing images on a JPanel (`getX()`, `getY()`, `getImage()`...), would it be understandable to call it `Drawable`? If not so, why not?

Comment: Giving clear names is in my opinion more important than to follow this convention. With several implementations I'd give them names `AdjacencyListGraph` and `AdjacencyMatrixGraph` for instance, and `Drawable` is a very good name for drawable stuff.

Comment: It is a common, but horrible Convention. I prefer the convention used in the Collection library. The interface says what it does, the class name says how it does it. E.g. List vs. ArrayList

Comment: In my opinion, using "Impl" as suffix for the implementation is really a horrible idea as @SeanPatrickFloyd said. Because, when you add "Impl" you do not have a clear purpose why you are using this class. When the purpose is clear, the naming will be available easier.