# Conventions for naming service classes

Tags: java, naming-conventions, service-layer

I'm developing a simple Java application for doing CRUD operations against a database through a RESTful API. It's divided into three layers: the controller layer, the service layer and the DAO layer.

Normally, I create a service interface for each domain object. Say, `User`:

```
public interface UserService {
  List<User> getAll();
  User create(User entity);
  void update(User entity) throws Exception;
  void delete(Long id) throws Exception;
}
```

Then I implement that interface in a service class:

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService { ... }
```

This approach I think has several drawbacks:

- It forces me to name the concrete class something other than `UserService`, although I only have one concrete implementation of that interface
- All the different services do not implement the same interface
- There's an explosion of interfaces that all behave the same way

#### Another approach

I'd create an interface that all services would implement:

```
public interface CrudService<T> {
  List<T> getAll();
  T create(T entity);
  void update(T entity) throws Exception;
  void delete(Long id) throws Exception;
}
```

So I choose the name `CrudService` to convey the functionality provided by that interface. Then, I have a concrete service class implementing that interface with a type parameter `User`:

```
public class UserService implements CrudService<User> { ... }
```

This way my services have names like `UserService` which I think is more clean and readable.

#### Questions

- What's the convention for naming service classes? What do you usually do?
- Should I name a concrete class `UserService` when that sounds like an interface?
- What about the `Impl` suffix? Does it convey anything about the implementation?

Comment: Do you really need an interface if you know that you will have only one concrete implemention or is it just to follow what some people blindly call 'best practices' ? Have a look at this interesting article: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/service_s_new_serviceimpl_why

Comment: @OlivierM. Excactly. Most of the time I create an interface before implementing the actual class just for the sake of using interfaces, because someone told me "using interfaces everywhere is good". Well I don't actually want that interface bloating my application given only one implementation which is likely never going to change. Here, there's only need for a single interface to tie together the services.

Comment: Probably, in most situations, you don't need interfaces.
If you are using EJB, for example, just annotate your bean with `@Stateless`, `@Stateful` or `@Singleton`.
But sometimes, interfaces are needed. With EJB, if you would like a remote service, you need an interface annotated with `@Remote`.
But do not let the exception becomes the rule. When a remote access is needed, create an interface with only the methods you would like to expose and make your bean implement it.

Comment: Note that when using a modern IoC framework like Spring (which is almost always the case for "*real*" webapp development nowadays), it would still be highly beneficial (not to say mandatory) to declare interfaces for your services, as it makes everything (the use of framework-specific syntax, unit testing in general etc.) a whole lot simpler.

Comment: @OlivierMasseau The "article" you cited is a poorly written opinion piece to address this issue IMHO :-)

Comment: @OlivierMasseau for "Do you really need an interface if you know that you will have only one concrete implemention" I can agree to this. But in modern web apps chances are there is always a cache layer implementation along with default service implementation. So chances are you start with at least two service implementations.

Comment: ```UserService userService = new DefaultUserService;
...
UserService cachedUserService = new CachedUserService;```

Answer (score 7):

To answer your questions:

- There is no "special" convention for naming **service** classes. They are classes so they should be a **noun(s)** in singular form in **CamelCase**: `Customer`, `Company`, `Employee`, `UserService`, `WrapperManager`, `FileStream`, etc.
- Just because `UserService` sounds like an interface to you it does not mean it is one. You also do not have to name your class `UserService` if you do not want to. It is up to you in the end.
- `Impl` sounds ugly and looks noisy. Do not use it. Do not use prefixes or other suffixes either. Use whole words. Remember the basics: classes are objects, so an `Apple` is an apple, not an `App`. Moreover, `Impl` does not convey anything about the implementation (aka business logic.)

For more info, check out the following great answers:

> - [Interface naming in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541912/interface-naming-in-java)
> - [Java Interfaces/Implementation naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814805/java-interfaces-implementation-naming-convention)
> - [Java Interface Naming Conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17275344/java-interface-naming-conventions)